# Numpy C API - Using PyArray_Descr for array creation causes segfaults

Tags: python, c++, numpy

I'm trying to use the Numpy C API to create Numpy arrays in C++, wrapped in a utility class. Most things are working as expected, but whenever I try to create an array using one of the functions taking a `PyArray_Descr*`, the program instantly segfaults. What is the correct way to set up the `PyArray_Descr` for creation?

An example of code which isn't working:

```
PyMODINIT_FUNC
PyInit_pysgm()
{
    import_array();
    return PyModule_Create(&pysgmmodule);
}

// ....

static PyAry zerosLike(PyAry const& array)
{
    PyArray_Descr* descr = new PyArray_Descr;
    Py_INCREF(descr); // creation function steals a reference
    descr->type = 'H';
    descr->type_num = NPY_UINT16;
    descr->kind = 'u';
    descr->byteorder = '=';
    descr->alignment = alignof(std::uint16_t);
    descr->elsize = sizeof(std::uint16_t);
    std::vector<npy_intp> shape {array.shape().begin(), array.shape().end()};
    // code segfaults after this line before entering PyAry constructor
    return PyAry(PyArray_Zeros(shape.size(), shape.data(), descr, 0));
}
```

(testing with uint16).

I'm not setting the `typeobj` field, which may be the only problem, but I can't work out what the appropriate value of type `PyTypeObject` would be.

**Edit**: [This page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/c-api.types-and-structures.html#scalararraytypes) lists the ScalarArray PyTypeObject instances for different types. Adding the line

```
descr->typeobj = &PyUShortArrType_Type;
```

has not solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using

```
descr = PyArray_DescrFromType(NPY_UINT16);
```

I've only recently been writing against the numpy C-API, but from what I gather the PyArray_Descr is basically the dtype from python-land. You should building these yourself and use the FromType macro if you can.

Comment: Whoops - I meant to come back to this - you're right, this is the answer I found.